# Why is my if-elif-else statement always returning the same answer?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

### Background:

I'm experimenting with while loops and I just made a simple program nested in a while loop.

### Code:

```
while True:
    userinput = input("Is nem jeff? ")
    if userinput == "y" or "yes" or "Y" or "Yes":
        print ("YAY!")
    elif userinput == "n" or "no" or "N" or "No":
        print ("das sad :(")
    else:
        print ("wrong input")
        break
```

### Problem:

My program should be looping until the user types in an invalid input, but instead, it always returns the value nested in the if statement, no matter what I type in. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The associated question is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conditionals aren't doing what you think they are.

In Python, a non-zero-length string evaluates to `True` in a boolean
context. The `or` operator performs a boolean `or` operation between
the lefthand operand and the righthand operand.

So when you write this:

```
if userinput == "y" or "yes" or "Y" or "Yes":
```

What you are saying is this:

```
if (userinput == "y") or True or True or True:
```

Which will *always* evaluate to True. You want to write instead:

```
if userinput == "y" or userinput == "yes" or userinput == "Y" or userinput == "Yes":
```

Or more simply:

```
if userinput.lower() in ['y', 'yes']:
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason false down to truthsy or falsy in if  conditions.
based on your initial code block

```
print('y'=='yes'or'y')
[output] y
print('n'=='yes'or'y')
[output] y
```

based on the above you can see that regardless of you input, your first if statement would be evaluated as True.
rather than doing that, try doing this instead.

```
while True:
    userinput = input("Is nem jeff? ").lower()
    if userinput in ['yes','y']:
        print ("YAY!")
    elif userinput in ['no','n']:
        print ("das sad :(")
    else:
        print ("wrong input")
        break
```

Comment: Answers should describe the problem and describe the solution, not just show code.